# Android run task every X seconds

Tags: android, sql, multithreading, layout

I have to get records from an MSSQL DB every 10 seconds and refresh my Layout. How can I achieve this?

When I run it in a new thread, I am not allowed to change the View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TimerTask should do what you want

Comment: http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/scheduling-a-timer-task-to-run-repeatedly/

Comment: ok, i have solved my problem with writing values in a global array and getting them from the main thread. Just didnt used your solutions. Because code is huge to reverse processing. Thanks everyone.